# Error On click Button Docmd Report Error 3464

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Hi Everyone How Are You I hope You Are Well.
I Am Working On A MS Access Application And Want Fetch Result From List Box With On Click Button
But I'm Facing A Error Data Type Mismatch In Criteria expression

Here is My Code On Click Button

```
Private Sub ViewBalance_Click()
'Dim listrpt As String
If IsNull(listrpt) Then
MsgBox "Please Select The Account Name", vbOKOnly, "Warning"
Exit Sub
End If

DoCmd.OpenReport "List All Parties Balance", acViewPreview, , "[Account ID] = """ & listrpt & 
""""
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

And Here is My On Report Load Filter But This Filter Working Fine Above Code Give me Error

Report Load Code

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

DoCmd.Maximize

If MsgBox("Do You Want To Filter Available Balance Only?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
Dim strFilter As String
strFilter = "[RQ]>0"
'verify that it looks good
Me.Filter = strFilter
Me.FilterOn = True
End If

End Sub
```

Report Name: List All Parties Balance
Query Name Where is Field Name: Account ID is: ListBalance

And listrpt Response Account ID = 60023

Please Anyone Give me A Support & Help Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `Account ID`? Is it stored within the database as text or a number?  If it's text does the table entry have a primary key which might be what you need to match against?

Comment: Hi Thanks For Reply Account ID is Stored as Number

Comment: `"[Account ID] = " & Me![listrpt] ` I Tried This But Not Work I Got All Result Instread Of Account ID

Comment: Account ID have Primary key

Comment: Try `DoCmd.OpenReport "List All Parties Balance", acViewPreview, , "[Account ID] = " & listrpt` or `DoCmd.OpenReport "List All Parties Balance", acViewPreview, , "[Account ID] = " & CLng(listrpt)`

Comment: Does `listRpt` hold the PK for Account ID?  i.e. Two columns, first with the PK and second with the Account ID - you probably need to match against the PK.

Comment: I have 3 Tables, Table1 = accounts, Table2=addbill, Table2=addcont table one fields ID, PK[Account ID], Party Name, Other Tables Have Same Fields but in Other Table PK is ID Only Table1 PK is Account ID T

Comment: Table1 is main Table Of Account Heads Relations With Other Table

Comment: Your Code Is working But Can't Filter Match Field Showing All Result Not Specific by [Account ID]

Comment: Table Relationship [Table Relationship Screenshot](https://ibb.co/CsqrbzN)

Comment: Why try to filter report in it's load event? Add the additional filter criteria to the OpenReport command.

Comment: However, trying to join two tables that are the 'many' side of a relationship to same parent table probably won't produce output you want.